# Linux (Ubuntu) run script upon USB mount

Tags: linux, ubuntu, scripting, mount, usb

I have a Ubuntu server with a external USB hard drive.

I basically just want to run a script whenever the hard drive is plugged in.

What would be the optimal way to achieve this ?

Comment: You may want to ask this on superuser.com instead.

Comment: Is this on a server, or a system with a GUI installed?

Comment: Server (killing the retarded 15 char minimum by comment)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can add a udev rule for your specific device -- to do this, create a file called /etc/udev/010custom.rules (or something similar; just make sure numerically it is the smallest in the directory). The files contents will be:

```
BUS="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}="**IDVENDOR**", SYSFS{product}="**PRODUCT**", NAME="usb/%k", SYMLINK="DEVICE"
RUN+="/path/to/your/script"
```

Replace the bolded keywords with the values for your device from `lsusb`:

Bus 005 Device 002: ID **0b05**:b700 **ASUSTek Computer, Inc. Broadcom Bluetooth 2.1**

The first bold field above is IDVENDOR, and the second bold field is PRODUCT.

As for DEVICE, you can define this yourself; it will create a /dev/ node which is a symlink to any device that fits the criteria above (so, if you put foobar as the SYMLINK, udev will create a /dev/foobar which is a symlink to your USB device).

**Note:** I haven't tried this myself as I don't have any removable USB devices, but it should work. If you have any trouble check the udev documentation for rules.

Comment: I apologize if my writing is hard to follow; I'm a programmer, not a linguist.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this should at least put me on the right path ;)

Comment: You may want to note that RUN is meant to be on a newline, separate from BUS-SYMLINK -- ServerFault is just kind of weird with how it handles newlines, so I added a code tag.

Comment: Oh.. I just added it at the end with a coma and it worked fine. However the script is called as expected .. but more than once. It's called like 15 times. I use the product and the device serial to match the device so I don't understand why.

Comment: That's a bit weird. Why not have the script create some sort of lock file in /tmp telling it not to run more than once? So, something like 'if file /tmp/usb-lock exists exit, else run script'

Comment: Yeah that's basically the workaround I planned to use.. thanks

Comment: the RUN needs to be on the end of the same line; each UDEV rule is one line.  the BUS-SYMLINK stuff acts as a filter to select the device that the RUN statement will be executed on.  if RUN is on its own line, it'll get added to (and thus run for) every device.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that you'll want to look at `udev`. Unfortunately, you've just witnessed me exhaust my knowledge of it.