# Linux: How do I run a script when an external drive is connected?

Tags: linux, backup, hard-drive

I've got a couple of remote servers in a school, and I'd like to set them up so that, as soon as someone (probably a teacher) plugs in an external hard disk, it will be mounted and the backup started.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: What OS are the servers running?

Comment: Gentoo and Debian.  Not sure off the top of my head which kernel version.

Comment: The accepted answer to this question is more detailed:
http://serverfault.com/questions/74593/linux-ubuntu-run-script-upon-usb-mount

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple ways of doing this:

- Modify your udev rules so that whenever a certain device is inserted, a script is run. See http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html#external-run for an example.
- Write a daemon that listens on dbus for device insertion messages and handles the event. (this is more work)

Comment: You know of any resource that covers having the script handled by the session of a certain user so that you can use GUI commands like in [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/582723/can-udev-somehow-trigger-zenity-for-a-logged-in-user-in-a-session)?